# Load SimpleCursorAdapter from an Array

Tags: android, arrays, simplecursoradapter

Is it possible to load a SimpleCursorAdapter from an Array of data i have made?
This is how a load my Array:

```
String[][] arrayStixoi = new String[countCategory][countCategory];
            int i = 0;
            while(ccget.moveToNext()){
                String stixoi = ccget.getString(ccget.getColumnIndex("stixoi"));
                String syggraf=ccget.getString(ccget.getColumnIndex("syggrafeas"));
                String notes=ccget.getString(ccget.getColumnIndex("syggrafeas"));
                String news=ccget.getString(ccget.getColumnIndex("syggrafeas"));
                arrayStixoi[i][0] = Integer.toString(i);
                arrayStixoi[i][1] = stixoi;
                arrayStixoi[i][2] = syggraf;
                arrayStixoi[i][3] = notes;
                arrayStixoi[i][4] = news;
                i++;
                String _id=arrayStixoi[i][0]+1;

            }
```

Now i want that Array: arrayStixoi to load a SimpleCursorAdapter and then add this adapter to a ListView.

Is this possible? and how?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: with an array, you'd better use an **ArrayAdapter**. (if you still want to use a cursoradapter, consider a MatrixCursor)

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet you have

```
ccget.moveToNext()
```

I assume `ccget` is an instance of `Cursor`. With that, you can just instantiate a `SimpleCursorAdapter` using its default constructor:

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter(
   this, R.layout.your_layout, 
   ccget, 
   from, 
   to,
   flags)
```

Please refer to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).